# Nsubstitute Calls Method in When even though there is DoNotCallBase

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, nsubstitute

I am partially mocking a class that has these two methods:

```
public void EmitTo(string connectionId, ChatMessage message)
{
    Clients.Client(connectionId).broadcastMessage(message.User.UserName, message.Message);
}

public virtual void Broadcast(ChatMessage message)
{
    Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message.User.UserName, message.Message);
}
```

In my test `[SetUp]` I have these calls:

```
hub = Substitute.ForPartsOf<ChatHub>(myMockedClient, context, groupManager);
hub.When(x => x.Broadcast(Arg.Any<ChatMessage>())).DoNotCallBase();
hub.When(x => x.EmitTo(Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<ChatMessage>())).DoNotCallBase();
```

I have no issues with the `Broadcast` call on this line or later on when I call the method (they do not do anything as expected) but oddly my third line throws an error:

> System.ArgumentException : Argument cannot be null or empty Parameter name: connectionId

I am a bit lost as I did the exact same thing for both methods and get a different behaviour, why does my when method call the `EmitTo`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NSubstitute like most mocking frameworks can only intercept calls to `virtual` methods.  It is able to stop the call to `Broadcast`, because it is virtual.  You need to make `EmitTo` virtual if you want to stop it being called.  It needs to be:

```
public virtual void EmitTo(string connectionId, ChatMessage message)
{
    Clients.Client(connectionId).broadcastMessage(message.User.UserName, message.Message);
}
```

Comment: I was so focussed on the rest I missed the basic, thanks a lot.

Comment: Correct answer is already given but I wanted to add a link to the documentation for other users as well: http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/